# Removing functions from a column, but keeping data (convert to normal text)?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have a column that contains the results of a few different formulas. I want to convert all of these cells to normal text, getting rid of the formulas.

I know I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 5):

1. Select the cells to convert.
2. Copy cells (with CTRL-C).
3. Select Edit from the menu.
4. Select Past Special from the menu.

   - In the dialog box that opens, unselect formulas and select the desired conditions and press OK.

Comment: There it is. I'd tried that, with only "Number" selected, and it didn't work. It worked this time, when I selected everything except "Formula"